# UIPopoverController jumps when textfield inside it becomesFirstResponder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverController which appears when i click a navigation button. I have a `UITextField` and `UITableView` inside the `UIPopoverController`. When the `textfield becomesFirstResponder` the `tableview` animates its height properly from `keyboardWillShow:`. But the whole popover kind of jumps while its animating.

I have set `self.contentSizeForViewInPopover` and also call `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:`. But it still does not work.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today and I worked around this issue by using grand central dispatch:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    sleep(0.2f);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
    });
  });
}
```

It is not a beauty, but it works and everything else I tried did not work.

Hope this helps
Lars